# How can I create a function that merges elements of three different lists into elements of one unique list?

Tags: python

Following up on my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74088925/how-to-check-for-several-keywords-in-a-text-file-and-append-whats-after-each-on) of yesterday, I now need to create a function that merges the outputs of three different lists into elements of one list using a function.

**Conditions:**

- Function with 3 different inputs, that correspond to the already 3 different existent lists (name, nationality, age);
- One output, which must be: return (results);
- These 3 lists came from a previously written function, which is the following:

  ```
    def read_information(file_name):
        name = []
        nationality = []
        age = []
        with open(file_name) as file:
            for line in file:
                if not line.strip():  # skips empty line
                    continue
                value = line.split(":")[1].strip()
                if line.startswith("Name"):
                    name.append(value)
                if line.startswith("Nationality"):
                    nationality.append(value)
                if line.startswith("Age"):
                    age.append(value)

        return name, nationality, age
  ```

**Example:**

```
Name       : Anthony Hopkins
Nationality: English
Age        : 23

Name       : Ezequiel Ruiz
Nationality: Spanish
Age        : 39
```

**Desired result in a list:**

```
[English Anthony Hopkins 23, Spanish Ezequiel Ruiz 39] -> etc for other elements
```

**My (poor) attempt**

I'm honestly completely lost, with no ideas. I don't have any clue where I could even start, so I tried this, but I think my approach may be wrong:

```
def order_information(nationality, name, age):
   
   name = []
   nationality = []
   age = []
   results= []
    
   with open("information.txt") as file:
       for line in file:
           if not line.strip():  # skips empty line
               continue
           value = line.split(":")[1].strip()
           if line.startswith("Name"):
               name.append(value)
           if line.startswith("Nationality"):
               nationality.append(value)
           if line.startswith("Age"):
               age.append(value)
    
    for name, nationality, age in results:
        results = nationality + name + age

    return results
```

Comment: Please fix your code formatting.

Comment: I've tried to fix the formatting, but it's not quite working.

Comment: I fixed the code formatting issue. It is actually an annoying feature of stackoverflow where if you put a code block immediately after a bulleted list, [it isn't recognized as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265765/1609514) due to the existing indent. You have to add a double indent or use the \`\`\` method.

Comment: Thank you so much Bill. I was quite confused, as I didn't know what I was doing wrong and the code wasn't coming well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a possible solution may be

```py
names=["Yurisleidis","Paco"]
nationalitys=["Cuba","Burundy"]
ages=[23,45]
results=[]

for name, nationality, age in zip(names,nationalitys,ages) :
    results.append(f"{nationality} {name} {age}")

print(results)
```

Where the `zip` function receive various enumerable objects, and return for every iteration a tuple with length equal to the total of enumerable objects, containing the element associated to the current iteration in every object.

Answer (score 1):

```
list(zip(nationality, name, age))
```

There is a zip command that's used for merging different arrays like the way you want.

(As per the comment below...good suggestion)

Comment: Maybe add `list(...)` in case the OP is not familiar with iterators.